# Indices to solve congruences

Tags: number-theory

I me struggling on this problem (attached)

I understand the first few steps: just take index of each side and using the indices rules. However the next step confuses me, why does I(8)-I(9)=3 mod 10

I thought to determine the index we need to know a (in these cases 8 and 9), the modulo n (in this case 10) and g such that:  a=g^r mod [image]n

Can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 1):

$$2^2\equiv4,2^3\equiv8,2^5=32\equiv-1\pmod{11}$$

$\displaystyle\implies2$ is a primitive root $\pmod{11}$

$\displaystyle\implies9\equiv-2\equiv2\cdot2^5\pmod{11}\iff$ind$_29=6$

Using [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html),

$9x^3\equiv8\pmod{11}\implies$ind$_29+3$ind$_2x\equiv$ind$_28\pmod{10}$

$\displaystyle\implies6+3$ind$_2x\equiv3\pmod{10}$

$\displaystyle\iff3$ind$_2x\equiv-3\iff$ind$_2x\equiv-1\equiv10\pmod{11}$

Comment: So you just choose the first primitive root and base all index calculations on that? Moreover, will I get the same answer for any primitive root I choose? Thanks a lot, I'm not 100% comfortable with this topic

Comment: @user136069, By the first, you mean the smallest, right? You can try with the rest of the primitive roots to be comfortable with the topic